# Word output issues using R Markdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, bibtex, csl

I was trying to output a Word document using APA bibliography style. When I compiled my document in order to output a PDF, there was no problem at all: citations were listed correctly in the references section. It was the same with HTML output. On the other hand, when I compiled my document using Word output, my references were not listed correctly... It was my debut. This is a correct version of my MWE:

This is a reference bib I use:

```
@Book{Assoun1981,
author = {Assoun, Paul-Laurent},
title = {Introduction à l'épistémologie freudienne},
publisher = {Éditions Payot},
address = {Paris},
year = {1981}, }
```

And this is my MWE:

```
---
title: "A title"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: biblatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: yes
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    df_print: paged
  word_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
date: "August 2022"
bibliography: YourLibraryName.bib
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: left=4cm,right=4cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm
linestretch: 1.5
toc-title: Plan
links-as-notes: yes
link-citations: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Mapping=tex-text]{Janson Text LT Std}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{headings}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
- \usepackage [french]{babel}
- \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
- \DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
- \DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
---

# Introduction

[@Assoun1981]

# Références
```

Comment: If you can create a .html doc and a PDF doc, is there a specific reason for word? Maybe academic? Can you share screenshot how your references are not rendering correctly, do you have the latest WORD  version?

Comment: @Daniel_j_iii: I've just edited my MWE and added a correct version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my MWE and added a correct version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).